# create-react-app build/serve environment variables

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Relatively new to working with react.   I have an application that is working fine in local docker.   I populate a bunch of REACT_APP_ environment variables by exporting them to the environment before starting the docker container.

Now, I'm trying to deploy this to a kubernetes pod by running a yarn build and then serving up the build.  I see that the environment variables are available on the pod itself by looking at `printenv` but the application doesn't appear to be picking them up.

Is there something special with serving a production build of a react-app to get it to see the exported environment variables that I'm missing?

I don't want to embed an .env file into the built docker image for security reasons, so I'm hoping that running a react build via serve can still pick up exported REACT_APP_ environment variables that are set via kubernetes secrets.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, whenever you build a react application with npm, static files are produced that don't know anything about any environment variables you may try to inject at runtime with Kubernetes.

The article below does a good job of explaining this and why they choose to attach the environment variables to the JavaScript window object since it has application-scope available to it.

[Making a React application container environment-aware at Kubernetes deployment](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/12/react-application-container-environment-aware-kubernetes-deployment/)